# How to set parent window values to child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set parent window values to child window?

In parent window i have few textboxes. When i enter some values and click on button i need to get those values in child window. I am using HTML and javascript. I need this in javascript or jquery. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have existing code we can look at? It's hard to know what to say apart from look at using jQuerys ajax controls with json and then write a handler to populate the fields

Answer (score 2):

In your parent window, you should have a function:

```
//parent window
function getParentValue(){
  return $("#textbox").val();
}
```

You can call this function in your child window:

//child window

```
var parentValue = window.opener.getParentValue();
alert(parentValue);
```

This works because functions are public by default (not like vars)

Hope this helps. Cheers